# Mongoose schema does not work when I try to save it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

> this is the code that i am exporting

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const carrito = new mongoose.Schema({
    nombre: String,
    precio: Number
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("carrito",carrito);
```

> this is the code where the error occurs, when i try to do the  **await carritoschema.save();**  the error below happen

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const carrito = require("./carrito");
const cors = require("cors");
const { json } = require("body-parser");
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/",async (req,res)=>{
    
    let {nombre,precio} = req.body;
    console.log(nombre +" "+ precio);

    let carritoschema = new carrito();
    carritoschema.nombre= nombre;
    carritoschema.precio = precio;
    await carritoschema.save();

    //await carritoschema.find(); 
});
app.get("/carrito",async (req,res)=>{ 
    
})
 

//app.get("/",async(req,res)=>{});
 
app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("listening on port 5000"); 
});
```

> this is the error but i have no idea how to fix it

```
(node:4372) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `carritos.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\reneo\Desktop\shopingWebsite\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:184:20)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:4372) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function 
without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)     
(node:4372) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need first of all configurate the database connection. There's a link that will help you: https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/simple-mongoose-and-node-js-example-1007 .

If you have any other doubt let me known.

Comment: you are a saviour

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I changed my database connection method from `mongoose.Createconnection(...)` to `mongoose.connect(...)` and I could save to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you have to set IP address to anywhere in your MongoDB Atlass in network tab